# Get data from NodeJS to Dart/Flutter using Socket.io

Tags: node.js, flutter, sockets, dart

I'm trying to get data from the NodeJS and I've no idea how to do this can someone help me? The packages used in this example are: import 'dart:async' and import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart';

testSocket.dart

```
 void testSocket(socket) async {
  Socket socket;
  try {
    // Configure socket transports must be sepecified
    socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:3000', <String, dynamic>{
      'transports': ['websocket'],
    });
    // Connect to websocket
    socket.connect();
    // THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO PRINT THE DATA THAT WE GOT RECIEVED FROM NODEJS
    socket.on('event', (data) => print(data));

  } 
  print("connected: ${socket.connected}");
}
```

index.js

```
    const server = require('http').createServer()

   const io = require('socket.io')(server)

io.on('connection', function (client) {
  client.on('event', function name(data) {
    data = "test";
    // Send data somehow to Flutter
    io.on();
  });
});

// The live server
var server_port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(server_port, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log('Listening on port %d', server_port);
});
```

I really appreciate it that you are taking time to help me out!

Comment: Your server is never sending anything to the client. Neither is the client sending anything. Try `socket.onConnect((_) { socket.emit('msg', 'test') });`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this code is only sending data to the server right? My question is how I get data from the server. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to emit events from your server and your client has to subscribe to those same events in order to receive data and updates.

> testSocket.dart

```dart
void testSocket(socket) async {
  Socket socket;
  try {
    socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:3000', <String, dynamic>{
      'transports': ['websocket'],
    });
    socket.connect();
    socket.on('testEvent', (data) => print(data));
  } 
  print("connected: ${socket.connected}");
}
```

And your server has to then emit the `testEvent` with some data.

> index.js

```js
const server = require('http').createServer()
const io = require('socket.io')(server)

io.on('connection', function (client) {
  client.on('event', function name(data) {
    data = "test";
    client.emit('testEvent', data);
  });
});

var server_port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(server_port, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log('Listening on port %d', server_port);
});
```

Now since we're firing just a one-off event, the data will only come once. You'd have to emit the same event in order for the clients to receive updates.